# Python pandas with split columns by text

Tags: python, pandas

I have data something like this and I am not sure how to split and convert into table.

I use pandas to sep by |, but I am not sure how to sep by | and = at the same time in this case.

Data sample is like this by txt:

```
SPK_VOLUME=|DEVICE_STATUS=|WAKE_UP=|SCS_STATUS=|SCS_CLASS=||MUSIC_URL_STATUS=|MUSIC_LOGIN_STATUS=|MUSIC_STREAMING_CONNECT_STATUS=|MUSIC_STREAMING_STATUS=|PLAYER_PLAYING_TIME=|TTS_STATUS=|TTS_CLASS=|ALARM_STATUS=|ALARM_END_REASON=|FOTA_STATUS=|FOTA_FAIL_REASON=
....
```

I loaded data with pandas

```
log_file = pd.read_csv("./log_file.txt",
                       sep = "|")
```

But, I also wanted to split by "=" and create table by values.

```
SPK_VOLUME  DEVICE_STATUS   WAKE_UP
5   22221   0
2   42241   2
3   125214  1
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing `sep=r'\=\|'`, this worked for me:

```
In [189]:

t="""SPK_VOLUME=|DEVICE_STATUS=|WAKE_UP=|SCS_STATUS=|SCS_CLASS=||MUSIC_URL_STATUS=|MUSIC_LOGIN_STATUS=|MUSIC_STREAMING_CONNECT_STATUS=|MUSIC_STREAMING_STATUS=|PLAYER_PLAYING_TIME=|TTS_STATUS=|TTS_CLASS=|ALARM_STATUS=|ALARM_END_REASON=|FOTA_STATUS=|FOTA_FAIL_REASON="""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=r'\=\|')
df.columns.tolist()

Out[189]:
['SPK_VOLUME',
 'DEVICE_STATUS',
 'WAKE_UP',
 'SCS_STATUS',
 'SCS_CLASS',
 '|MUSIC_URL_STATUS',
 'MUSIC_LOGIN_STATUS',
 'MUSIC_STREAMING_CONNECT_STATUS',
 'MUSIC_STREAMING_STATUS',
 'PLAYER_PLAYING_TIME',
 'TTS_STATUS',
 'TTS_CLASS',
 'ALARM_STATUS',
 'ALARM_END_REASON',
 'FOTA_STATUS',
 'FOTA_FAIL_REASON=']
```

Alternatively you can just call [`.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html#pandas.Series.str.rstrip) on the `.columns` attribute as a post-processing step:

```
In [192]:
df.columns = df.columns.str.rstrip('=')
df.columns.tolist()

Out[192]:
['SPK_VOLUME',
 'DEVICE_STATUS',
 'WAKE_UP',
 'SCS_STATUS',
 'SCS_CLASS',
 'Unnamed: 5',
 'MUSIC_URL_STATUS',
 'MUSIC_LOGIN_STATUS',
 'MUSIC_STREAMING_CONNECT_STATUS',
 'MUSIC_STREAMING_STATUS',
 'PLAYER_PLAYING_TIME',
 'TTS_STATUS',
 'TTS_CLASS',
 'ALARM_STATUS',
 'ALARM_END_REASON',
 'FOTA_STATUS',
 'FOTA_FAIL_REASON']
```

Comment: Gratz on 100k :-)

Comment: @piRSquared thanks, [swag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291791/what-do-i-get-with-100k-reputation) on it's way

Comment: @EdChum - Congrat to 100k ;)